# HTML Object data URL from dynamic source

Tags: javascript, java, html, http-headers

So all uploads for my app are not stored in my web server space, they are stored in a file system storage.  When my users want access to the file they call a URL and the backend process will buffer the data to the browser via the HttpServletResponse outputstream.  This works great as intended for downloading a file.  Now my use-case has a scenario where I need to load an embedded object using this same method.

I am essentially loading a preview of the PDF file in the browser.  This works fine if the PDF is stored on the web server and I provide a direct URL to the file.  But when I use my method of sending files to the user then it doesn't work.

```
<object data='"+pdfUrl+"' type='application/pdf' width='160px' height='160px' />
```

If i put `pdfURL` into a browser my file gets downloaded no problem.  So I think the issue is the HTTP headers I am sending in the outputstream that maybe is preventing the Object from loading properly.  I am not sure if maybe its expecting something specific to be set in order to trigger loading the file

I am currently using very basic headers as follows:

```
BufferedInputStream is = <Some File Inputstream>;
resp.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(directory+filename));
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;  filename="+StringFormatHelper.formatFileName(filename));
bufferedCopy(is, resp.getOutputStream());
is.close();
resp.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I have to change to get the data to properly load in the Object tag?  I don't get any errors in the JS console or server side.  I am not sure how to debug this issue.

Edit: 
SO i just realized that if i right click on where the blank Object tag is at I have the option to "Save as..." and when I do I download the PDF.  So the pdf data is loaded but Its just not displaying in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line of code

```
resp.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(directory+filename));
```

This was not setting the correct mime-type for the file as I thought it was.  So there was a mismatch in that the Object tag was looking for `application/pdf` but the server was sending a different MIME type in the header.  Once I matched them up everything worked.

I was able to get the correct MIME type using the Spring provided lookup instead of the JDK lookup

```
new ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap().getContentType(directory+filename)
```